# Is there a way to get facepile to show people who liked my page

Tags: facebook

It seems like this question has been beaten to death, but I'm seeing different (conflicting) answers.

The developers page at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/
says,"To display users who have liked your page, specify the URL of your page as the href parameter."

That makes sense, but later on the same page it says...

"Why is nothing displaying?

The plugin only displays friends photos. If the user does not have friends who have liked your page or have connected to your site, no faces will be shown.

(((I've had several friends "like" the site, but their pictures don't show.)))

If you are displaying users who have liked your page, and no users have liked it yet, the plugin will render nothing.

(((Not the case here.)))

If some users have liked your page, but none of the viewing users friends have liked it, the plugin will display the total number of users who have liked your page.

(((This is what I get, "## people have liked this" So, if I understand this, someone comes to the website and likes it, their pic doesn't go to my facepile. They've got to get THEIR friend(s) to like my page to get a picture to show in facepile--not sure if it's the original guy who "liked" my page, or his friends who later "liked" it.)))

This all sounds kind of dumb to me.

What I'd like is to have it so when somebody "likes" my page, they show up in my facepile as someone who "liked" my page.

Some of the posts out there that I've read seem to say it works that way, but I've not been able to make it so.

Any help / suggestions.

Oh, if you want to see what I'm working on / with, it's at: http://www.theantinmarketinggroup.com/home

Sincere thanks for any answers.

Warmly,
B

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, is it a coding question ?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue until I found a similar plugin: [Facebook Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). This one *does* show all the people who "like" a page, publicly, *even while completely logged out of Facebook*!

I knew there had to be a way, because I saw other websites do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried to do it with facebook-php-sdk, but it seems, what it's not possible to show people who likes the url, if the siteusers are not connected.

Answer (score -3):

> What I'd like is to have it so when somebody "likes" my page, they show up in my facepile as someone who "liked" my page.

Without the viewer being friends with them?

No – for a reason called *privacy*.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think anything to do with facebook was very private. Besides, if they already "liked" the page, aren't already they putting it out in public?

Comment: Many FB users have their privacy setting set to Public.  There is no violation of privacy there.